# Target XML children with PHP

Tags: php, xml

I have an xml document that I'm getting the contents of 'value' to store as a PHP variable for checking and filtering purposes.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Event>
<Attributes>
    <EventAttribute>
        <Name>Event Type</Name>
        <Value>Cinema</Value>
    </EventAttribute>
    <EventAttribute>
        <Name>Venue</Name>
        <Value>Bonanza</Value>
    </EventAttribute>
</Attributes>
</Event>
```

I used the following PHP code:

```
<?php
$xml=simplexml_load_file("event.xml");
$typeevent = $xml->Attributes->EventAttribute[0]->Value;////should be Cinema
$typevenue = $xml->Attributes->EventAttribute[1]->Value;//should be Bonanza
echo "<p>" . $typeevent . "</p>";
echo "<p>" . $typevenue . "</p>";
?>
```

Which gives me the following output which works fine:

**Cinema**

**Bonanza**

**The Problem:**

New  nodes can be added by the system that I have no control over and thus will mess up the ordering so EventAttribute[1] could now reference something totally different.
I've done some research and I just can't get my heads around it. Ideally I want something like:

$typeevent = $xml->Attributes->EventAttribute-> -- where 'name' = 'EventType' give me the 'value'.

$typevenue = $xml->Attributes->EventAttribute-> -- where 'name' = 'Venue' give me the 'value'.

Hope this makes sense?

Comment: I'd suggest using XPath

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think if you want to access the members in that style, you'll need to generate an Associative Array, keyed to `EventAttribute->Name`:

```php
<?php

$xmlstring = <<<XML
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Event>
<Attributes>
    <EventAttribute>
        <Name>Event Type</Name>
        <Value>Cinema</Value>
    </EventAttribute>
    <EventAttribute>
        <Name>Venue</Name>
        <Value>Bonanza</Value>
    </EventAttribute>
</Attributes>
</Event>
XML;
```

```php
$event = simplexml_load_string($xmlstring, "SimpleXMLElement", LIBXML_NOCDATA);

$event_attributes = [];
foreach ($event->Attributes->EventAttribute as $event_attribute) {
  // Note, explicitly casting values to strings.
  $event_attributes[(string)$event_attribute->Name] = (string)$event_attribute->Value;
}

echo $event_attributes['Event Type'] . PHP_EOL;
echo $event_attributes['Venue'] . PHP_EOL;

print_r($event_attributes);
```

Output:

```
Cinema
Bonanza
Array
(
    [Event Type] => Cinema
    [Venue] => Bonanza
)
```

Comment: Thanks for that, after figuring out what you had done I've applied it and it works great. I've ran tests with all of the nodes mixed up with extra ones added, works!

Answer (score 3):

If you were to use `DOMDocument` you could then use `DOMXPath` and target the nodes you want using a fairly simple syntax regardless of the order of nodes in the XML source or the number.

A very useful XPath reference [can be found here](http://scraping.pro/res/xpath-cheat/xpath_css_dom_recipes.pdf)

```
<?php

    $xml='<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <Event>
    <Attributes>
        <EventAttribute>
            <Name>Event Type</Name>
            <Value>Cinema</Value>
        </EventAttribute>
        <EventAttribute>
            <Name>Venue</Name>
            <Value>Bonanza</Value>
        </EventAttribute>
    </Attributes>
    </Event>';

    $dom=new DOMDocument;
    $dom->loadXML( $xml );
    $xp=new DOMXPath( $dom );


    /* helper functions */
    function getnode( $xp, $ref, $query ){
        return $xp->query( $query, $ref )->item(0) ?: false;
    }
    function getvalue($node){
        return $node->nodeValue;
    }



    $type=getnode( $xp, null, '//EventAttribute/Name[ text()="Event Type" ]' );
    $value=getnode( $xp, $type->parentNode, 'Value' );
    printf("%s -> %s<br />\n", getvalue( $type ), getvalue( $value ) );



    $type=getnode( $xp, null, '//EventAttribute/Name[ text()="Venue" ]' );
    $value=getnode( $xp, $type->parentNode, 'Value' );
    printf("%s -> %s<br />\n", getvalue( $type ), getvalue( $value ) );

?>
```

This will output:

```
Event Type -> Cinema
Venue -> Bonanza
```

I'm not familiar with `SimpleXML` and it's associated methods so there may well be an equivalent to the `DOMXPath` class used here, I don't know.

If you do not wish to return the value stored within the `Name` element itself but merely grab the value you can target that node specifically using a sibling selector

```
$value=getvalue( getnode( $xp, null, '//EventAttribute/Name[ text()="Event Type" ]/following-sibling::Value' ) );
echo $value;    // outputs Cinema
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm using SimpleXML to do pretty much everything in the rest of my script so I can't change. However that's a good point on sibling selectors and equivalents in SimpleXML, I'm looking into that now. cheers